# React project crashing Visual Studio after NPM package update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, npm, package.json

I took over a ASP.net solution with multiple projects in Visual Studio (Professional 2017), one of these projects is in React. I have some experience with React-Native, but I am rather new to React, plus I am new to the code base I inherited.

Since the project was using many outdated and potentially insecure packages (according to `npm audit`), I decided to update using NPM by carefully replacing some `^1.2.3` with `*` inside my `package.json` (see below) as I read somewhere that this is common procedure.

Although there are no errors displayed in Visual Studio's Error List, the React project has troubles to compile and I am seeing an empty page in the browser. The error code is

```
index.tsx:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (51:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
|         <Provider store={store}>
|             <Layout>
    at eval (index.tsx:1)
    at Object../src/index.tsx (bundle.js:96)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:84
    at bundle.js:87
(anonymous) @ index.tsx:1
./src/index.tsx @ bundle.js:96
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:20
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:84
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:87
```

This looks like some webpack issue, but the exact error message is changing while I am trying to resolve the dependencies.

More curiously, **my IDE is crashing after a few minutes, while contentiously creating files named `VMxx`,** see my screenshot of the solution explorer

[image]

Inside those files I find e.g.

```
window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ && window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.size > 0
```

Clearly, something went wrong with the package update. But what does the described behavior mean? Can I deduce which packages I better should not have updated?

#### Package.json before

```
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "download": "^6.2.5",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "15.5.3",
    "react-dom": "15.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.14.8",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "15.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.40",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "^5.0.0",
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.17.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
}
```

#### Package.json afterwards

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "*",
    "@types/react-select": "*",
    "antd": "2.10.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "download": "6.2.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "*",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-redux": "*",
    "react-router-dom": "*",
    "react-router-redux": "*",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "0.14.8",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.23",
    "@types/react-redux": "4.4.40",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.0",
    "ajv": "^6.10.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "*",
    "less": "2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "4.1.0",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "ts-loader": "2.0.3",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.40.2"
  }
```

Comment: You need a correct preset to transpile JSX, can't see your webpack or .babelrc so I assume it might be missing:https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react. Also not sure why you're using `*` for versions, better specify the versions you want to be installed.

Comment: @Clarity Thanks for your hint, I will look into that. I just updated my question explaining why I was using the `*`. I realized now, that I probably should have used `npm --save install <package-to-update>@latest` to update. Anyhow, the most curious thing is why my Visual Studio is crashing.